# How do I stop gmail from loading its tour every time I open the app?

Tags: gmail, ios

Gmail is loading its tour of the 'new' gmail features (primary/social/promotion sections) every time I open my app on my ipad. I've completed the tour many times hoping that would stop it from popping up, but every time I open gmail, it prompts me with a tour. I'm using ios 7 on a mini retina if that helps.

Comment: Have you checked the box "do not show again?"